# Angular ng-show on selection of inputs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-show

i have a 4 input boxes onfocus of first text box it should show a div(Numpad) ,
after user enters 1 number in that text box, second textbox is foxused automatically  focused and so on , if he clicks backspace it clears the current text box 
hide conditions are 1. click outside of 4 text boxes
2. 4 text boxes are filled

which one should i use $touched
ng-blur
or using ng-dirty class

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: Please post some code